# What does "which is also the twin" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> According to the lot, therefore, India fell unto Judas Thomas,
>   ***which is also the twin***: but he would not go, saying that by reason of the weakness of the flesh he could not travel,... (Acts of
>   the Holy Apostle Thomas: Act I)

What does "which is also the twin" mean? Does it mean the lot fell unto India two times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Which* was an older way of saying *who*. So the passage is saying that [Judas Thomas](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostle_Thomas) was also the *twin*, or perhaps also called the *Twin*.

Etymology online says, about *[which](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Which&searchmode=none):*

> In Middle English used as a relative pronoun where Modern English would use *who*, as still in the Lord's Prayer.

Other [English transactions](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0823.htm) leave *twin* in Greek, one of the languages that the *[Gospel of Thomas](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Thomas)* survives in. This word is *[didymus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/didymous)*.

The King James Version of the Bible (original, 1611) also leaves *Didymus* untranslated:

> Then said Thomas, **which** is called Didymus, unto his fellow disciples, Let us also go, that we may die with him.

([John 11:16](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/John-11-16/)) Notice the use of *which* again, where nowadays we would use *who*.

I think this covers the question from a *language* point of view, which is the scope of ELL.

For possible answers as to *why* Thomas was known as Didymus (twin), you could see the answers to *[Who was Thomas's twin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14874/who-was-thomass-twin)* on Christianity Stack Exchange.